# Authentication pop up using robot not working in parallel execution in selneium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

I am executing a script which has an authentication popup and with Robot class it's working perfectly fine. If I execute tests in parallel then it's entering the username twice in the username field of the authentication popup username and in the other popup it's not entering any data.

For example: It's entering the data as username1username1 in the first popup.

Please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

Because if any popup like alert box is open in one window , you have to handle that popup and close it first. Then only it will allow you to access other windows. Both the pop up has same field name to find and send key "username1" in the textbox. So, where ever driver is finding that popup it is sending that value. In parallel execution it is working correctly. You need to find another way for the parallel execution.

Comment: Thanks a lot Yojna.We thought of using Auto it but we will be running scripts against Mac OS and AUTO IT doesn't support Mac OS,hence used Robot.Please let me know if there is any other solution for parallel execution ,as far as i Know its Auto it or Robot class we can handle the Authentication pop up.Please help

Comment: You can use threads to delay execution. You can use selenium WebDriverWait Class.

Comment: I tried using robot.delay(5000); but still its not working.could you please tell me how can i implement this solution

Comment: You need to find a tutorial and understand Robot framework first. I am not familiar with Robot framework. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0F_uIe7we6k

Comment: Thanks Yojna.I will go through the video.In the meantime if any one has any suggestion please let me know.